# How can i upload a file into a ftp server?

Tags: java, ftp, apache-commons, apache-commons-net

SOLVED

I'm making a desktop aplication that must be in touch with a ftp server, the files that will upload are images. I'm trying it but I can't upload despite being connected, the problem is when I want to upload the file, the method doesn't work and returns false. the code is the following:

```
public boolean subeFTP(String archivoLocal, String archivoServer){
    boolean resultado=false;

    FTPClient ClienteFTP=new FTPClient();

    //Se toma el nombre del archivo local
    String aux = archivoLocal;
    aux = aux.substring(aux.lastIndexOf("\\")+1);

    try {
        //Establece el timeout del servidor en 5 minutos para evitar desconexiones
        ClienteFTP.setControlKeepAliveTimeout(300);

        //Conexión al servidor
        ClienteFTP.connect(prop_servidor, prop_puertoServidor);

        //Pone el ftp en modo pasivo para recibir un archivo, permanecerá así mientras no se cambie
        ClienteFTP.enterLocalPassiveMode(); 

        //Login
        resultado=ClienteFTP.login(prop_usuarioFtp, prop_passFtp);


        //Comprobación de la conexión
        int reply = ClienteFTP.getReplyCode(); 
        if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)) {
            ClienteFTP.logout();
            ClienteFTP.disconnect();
               throw new Exception("El servidor FTP ha rechazado la conexión, error:\n" + ClienteFTP.getReplyString()); 
        }


        //Se cambia el directorio al requerido
        resultado = resultado && ClienteFTP.changeWorkingDirectory(prop_directorioServidor);


        //Tipo de archivo y envío
        resultado = resultado && ClienteFTP.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
        //resultado = resultado && ClienteFTP.setFileTransferMode(FTP.BLOCK_TRANSFER_MODE);


        BufferedInputStream buffIn=new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(archivoLocal));
        resultado = resultado && ClienteFTP.storeFile(archivoServer+aux, buffIn);
        System.out.println(ClienteFTP.getReplyString());

        buffIn.close();
        ClienteFTP.logout();
        ClienteFTP.disconnect();

        resultado=true;

    } catch (SocketException e) {
        System.out.println("Fallo 1");
        e.printStackTrace();
        resultado=false;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Fallo 2");
        resultado=false;
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        resultado=false;
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return resultado ;
}
```

Comment: What returns true? Your method or storeFile?

Comment: is there connection timeout ?  try setting  ftpClient.setControlKeepAliveTimeout(300);  (from documentation http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html). Also use  ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode() if you are uploading file.

Comment: No, the problem is when I try to set the file transfer mode and storing the file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should enter in local passive mode. use following methd  `ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode()`

According to documentation

> Set the current data connection mode to
>   PASSIVE_LOCAL_DATA_CONNECTION_MODE . Use this method only for data
>   transfers between the client and server. This method causes a PASV (or
>   EPSV) command to be issued to the server before the opening of every
>   data connection, telling the server to open a data port to which the
>   client will connect to conduct data transfers. The FTPClient will stay
>   in PASSIVE_LOCAL_DATA_CONNECTION_MODE until the mode is changed by
>   calling some other method such as enterLocalActiveMode()

I would also suggest you to call `ftpClient.setControlKeepAliveTimeout(timeoutInMilliseconds);`

```
Set the time to wait between sending control connection keepalive messages when processing file upload or download.
```

Comment: before or after the connection?

Comment: after you login. rather i would suggest before uploading file. means in your case after you set File type.

Comment: Also validate connection is proper not int reply = ClienteFTP.getReplyCode();
        if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)) {
           //connection to Server is not proper;
        }

Comment: I have changed it, thanks, but is broken yet, my connection is positive, thanks, i added it to my code. I have updated the code, at the end added notes.

Comment: Thank you people, with every one of your comments my code has been improoving until it worked, i'll mark thisone as the answer for the people who could need something similar for looking at and i'll update my code with the right one in order to help any people with troubles.